# Can JBoss RESTEasy Web Services Use x509 Certificates for Security?

Tags: web-services, jboss, x509certificate, resteasy

I am currently in the process of re-writing a legacy asp.net 2.0 web service as a JBoss RESTEasy web service.  The asp.net web service uses x509 certificates for security/authentication purposes.  Does JBoss RESTEasy support x509 certificates?  If not, what are some of the other security options that I can use with JBoss RESTEasy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here is an example in the documentation:

RESTEasy JAX-RS [38.2. Message Body Encryption](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/ch38.html#d0e3082)

Comment: Thanks j4y, I was reading that document but hadn't got up to that chapter just yet.  Much appreciated!